# jQuery consuming a json wcf C# service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

This is what my service looks like.
I have a class and an Interface. My services is exposed and I can call them via the wcftestClient tool.

Am I able to consume the web service like this with my jQuery ?

The problem I have is calling it in jQuery. It returns in JSON format.
I get the following error in firebug.

> Status Code:
>       HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

.cs

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
        {

            if (obj == null)
            {
                string temp = "";
                temp = "";
                obj = temp;
            }

            var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
            string returnValue = "";
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var xmlWriter = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(memoryStream))
                {
                    jsonSerializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj);
                    xmlWriter.Flush();
                    returnValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
        }

        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
```

Interface

```
 [OperationContract]        
        string HelloWorld();
```

jQuery

```
 function GetService() {
                            var BizName = $('#txtBizName').val();
                            //alert(BizName);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "http://www.website.com/WCFService/EdWebService.svc?HelloWorld",
                                type: "GET",
                                dataType: "json",                               
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                success: function(msg) {
                                    $('#status').html('Output: '+msg['d']['Id']);
                                },
                                error: function(e) {
                                    $('#status').innerHTML = "Unavailable";
                                }                               
                            });

                            alert(BizName);
                        }
```

Comment: By the way, do you have your page with jQuery and WCF service on the same domain and port?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `url: "http://www.website.com/WCFService/EdWebService.svc?HelloWorld"`
with `url: "http://www.website.com/WCFService/EdWebService.svc/HelloWorld"` at first.

Reason: you are not calling HelloWorld method, instead you pass 'HelloWorld' as parameter (in a very wrong way) to some unknown method (I don't know to which method resolves service name without method specified) of your service.

Then it should work. Please update your question if it doesn't.

Comment: I have a method thats called HelloWorld that does not no arguments and returns a string "HelloWorld". How would I call this ?
This url show a wsdl http://www.website.com/WCFService/EdWebService.svc?HelloWorld and the following url returns error 400 http://www.website.com/WCFService/EdWebService.svc/HelloWorld when added to a browsers url.

Comment: @KrivahnDoss please try changing GET to POST in $ajax call. The URL I provided is correct, as error 404 (not found) is now replaced with error 400 (bad request). Now you should create the proper request.